# Filter ListBox by text got from a TextBox in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listbox

I'm developing an application in C# using WPF in which I have a list of users. I already made the binding for each users' information to the `ListBox` and it's showing information.

What I want one is filter that ListBox using a `TextBox` field. I want the `ListBox` to be filetered each time the user enters a new letter (onKeyPress). I would like to use bindings if possible.

Where can I start from?

**EDIT:** I'm trying to filter the `ObservableCollection` like this:

```
        public ObservableCollection<UserTemp> TempObservableUsers { get; set; }

    public MainWindow()
    {

        TempObservableUsers = new ObservableCollection<UserTemp>();
        InitializeComponent();

        // Init fake users list and DataContext
        InitFakeList();
        DataContext = this;
    }

private void InitFakeList()
    {
        TempObservableUsers.Clear();
        for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
        {
            UserTemp user = new UserTemp("Username: " + i, i); 
            TempObservableUsers.Add(user);
        }
    }

 private void TextBoxSearchSuspect_PreviewKeyUp(object sender, System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        TempObservableUsers = TempObservableUsers.Where(temp => (temp.Name).IndexOf(TextBoxSearchSuspect.Text, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) > 0)
            .ToList<UserTemp>().ToObservableCollection();
    }

....}

    public static class Extensions
{
    public static ObservableCollection<T> ToObservableCollection<T>(this IEnumerable<T> col)
    {
        return new ObservableCollection<T>(col);
    }
}
```

**The xaml:**

```
<ListBox Name="ListBoxUsers" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=TempObservableUsers, ElementName=SuspectsWindow}" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" />
```

But these lines are not working. As the list is `a new one`, the list doesn't see it. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: use linq and filter the collection you bind the ListBox with the TextBox value

Comment: For those who have doubts on how to achieve that, I got the final answer in this link: http://jacobmsaylor.com/?p=1270 and combined with the PreviewKeyUp event.